# Turan's theorem for balanced r-partite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

I'm curious about the following restricted version of Turan's theorem:

Among all $r$-partite graphs that are balanced (exactly $n/r$ nodes per part), what is the maximum size of a graph with no $r$-cliques?

Comment: Do you mean simple graphs (i.e. not hypergraphs)?  And by maximum size do you mean "most edges"?

Comment: @TravisJ Yes to both.

Comment: You can get "easy" bounds in the following way: for an upper-bound, just use Turan's theorem without this restriction.  You'll see that if you have more than $\binom{n}{2}(1-\frac{1}{r-1}+\epsilon)$ edges then you are guaranteed to have an $r$-clique (provided $n$ is large enough); here $\epsilon$ can be any small positive constant.  You can get a lower bound by counting the edges in the graph which is $r$-partite, but one set of vertices has no edges adjacent to it, the rest is a complete $r-1$-partite graph.